# merge csv unix based on column 1

Tags: html, unix, awk

Hi I have two csv files having same columns like,

**`x.csv`**

```
column1,column2
A,2 
B,1
```

**`y.csv`**

```
column1,column2
A,1
C,2
```

I want the output like:

**`z.csv`**

```
column1,column2
A,2
B,1
C,2
```

i.e. for the matching data in first column, I want to keep the `x.csv` record and for a new field in `y.csv` (like A,2) i just want to append it (like C,2).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; print; next} ! ($1 in a)' x.csv y.csv
column1,column2
A,2 
B,1
C,2
```

#### How it works

- `-F,`

  This tells awk to use a comma as the field separator
- `NR==FNR{a[$1]; print; next}`

  While reading the first file (`NR==FNR`), this tells awk to (a) to add `$1` as a key to the associative array `a`, (b) print the line, and (c) skip the remaining commands and jump to the `next` line in a file.
- `! ($1 in a)`

  If we get here, that means we are working on the second file.  In that case, we print the line if the first field is not a key of array `a` (in other words, if the first field did not appear in the first file).

Comment: @EdMorton I know it works that way for awks I use.  Do you know if it is guaranteed to work that way?  I have not found this issue documented in POSIX.

Comment: Is the `next` statement really neccessary since the `! ($1 in a)` will never match the first file?

Comment: @EdMorton Very good.  Thanks!  Answer updated to remove `=1`.